# Keep reading numbers until newline reached using a Scanner

Tags: java, input, numbers, java.util.scanner

I want to read a couple of numbers from the console. The way I wanna do this is by having the user enter a sequence of numbers separated by a space. Code to do the following:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextInt()){
    int i = sc.nextInt();

    //... do stuff with i ...
}
```

The problem is, how do I stop when reaching a new line (while keeping the easy-to-read code above)? Adding a !hasNextLine() to the argument above makes it quit the loop instantly. One solution would be reading the whole line and the parse out the numbers, but I think the kinda ruins the purpose of the hasNextInt() method.

Comment: so if there are numbers on a different line you don't want it to read them?

Comment: Exactly, since there is no other way to stop the reading the input (afaik) than having the user type something else than a number, which to me seems less user friendly (edit: Which means I think enter would be the most intuitive way to stop reading the sequence).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to set the delimiter like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
while (sc.hasNextInt()){
    int i = sc.nextInt();

    //... do stuff with i ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The above code works well if the user inputs a number and then hits enter. When pressing enter without having entered a number the program the loop will terminate.

If you need (understood it more as a suggestion for usability) to enter the numbers space separated, have a look at the following code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Pattern delimiters = Pattern.compile(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"|\\s");
sc.useDelimiter(delimiters); 
while (sc.hasNextInt()){
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    //... do stuff with i ...
    System.out.println("Scanned: "+i);
}
```

It uses a `Pattern` for the delimiters. I set it to match a white space or a line separator. Thus the user may enter space separated numbers and then hit enter to get them scanned. This may be repeated with as many lines as necessary. When done the user just hits enter again without entering a number. Think this is pretty convenient, when entering many numbers.

Comment: -1. I'm quite sure (as in "I've tested it") that this will not work - `useDelimiter(x)` says that `x` is the _only_ valid token delimiter. Hence, if you try to enter e.g. "42 314", Java will see that entire line as one token, which is not a valid (single) int. Hence, there is no "next int", and the loop terminates.

Comment: @Aasmund: You're right. It does not work with "42 314" as I had a slightly different user guidance in mind. I normally enter number with the number pad, which makes return a very convenient separator. Updated the answer with a Pattern as delimiter. Think this is a rather good match when one does want to keep it clean with _one_ scanner.

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for! You may also add a space at the end of a number to terminate the loop. (Thou I would like a single enter press  to terminate ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use sc.nextLine() to read an input line, and then construct a new Scanner from that String (there is a constructor overload that takes a String) and read the ints from the second Scanner. (Note: If this is what you meant by "reading the whole line and the parse out the numbers", I'll delete this answer, but it looked like you were talking about manually reading the numbers with Integer.parseInt()).

Comment: In that case I think it would be better to read the original line using `BufferedReader`

Comment: It's pretty much what I meant with that sentence but still a more clean solution than the one I had in my head ;) So please, keep it!

Comment: @argote why? I personally find Scanner to be much more effective than BufferedReader for things like this.

Comment: @argote Are you implying that the performance of `Scanner` getting a line is significantly less efficient than `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @glowcoder: As far as I know it is, it won't impact much for a single line but in large datasets it can be significant. I used to participate in ACM-ICPC competitions and heard this often.

Comment: @Argot I was also in ACMs (and non-acm sanctioned competitions) and haven't found or heard that to be the case. Nor in my career as a java developer have I heard that to be the case. When I look at the source of the two, I find that `BufferedReader.readLine()` is synchronized, while `Scanner.nextLine()` is not, which makes me think that Scanner is actaully MORE efficient for this.

Comment: @glowcoder: After some research in Google it seems you are correct. I might run some experiments later tonight.