# Scanner never stops reading input

Tags: java.util.scanner

I'm simply trying to read integers (separated by spaces, such as : "6 9 20") from the console and transferring them into an array for later use. However, with the code I currently have written, my scanner object never stops reading my input. I feel like the scanner object simply doesn't know exactly when to stop taking input, but I'd like it to stop reading as soon as I hit Enter. I've searched this website extensively for a precise answer, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
        int[] mcNug = new int[5];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt() && scanner.hasNext())
        {
          list.add(scanner.nextInt());
          mcNug[i] = (int) list.get(i);
          i++;
          scanner.next();
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071458/keep-reading-numbers-until-newline-reached-using-a-scanner

Answer (score 0):

use a `nextLine()`.

```
while( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");
  ... do something with numbers array ..
}
```